# LESS multiple immediate children

Tags: less, siblings

Expected CSS:

```
.parent > .type1 {
    color: red;
}
.parent > .type2 {
    color: red;
}
.parent > .type3 {
    color: red;
}
```

Original LESS:

```
.parent {
    & > .type1, & > .type2, & > .type3 {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

How can I combine type1/type2/type3?
This doesn't work, because type2/type3 will be compiled to descendents, not immediate children:

```
.parent {
    & > .type1, .type2, .type3 {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it's a bit unclear (what you mean by "combining"), please specify what CSS you're actually expecting to get.

Comment: FYI `>` represents neither sibling nor adjacent sibling :)

Answer (score 5):

With LESS, `&` will be replaced with the entirety of the wrapping selector.

This means that

```
.parent {
  & > .type1, .type2, .type3 {...}
}
```

becomes

```
.parent > .type1, .type2, .type3 {...}
```

As you want to make your code more concise, you should note that the `>` combinator is *not* optional, however the `&` becomes redundant. An appropriate way of writing this selector would be:

```
.parent {
  > .type1,
  > .type2,
  > .type3 {...}
}
```

Which in turn produces'

```
.parent > .type1,
.parent > .type2,
.parent > .type3 {...}
```